# How to extract Key-Value pairs from a string, when the Key itself is the separator?

Tags: c#, regex, string, key-value

Say there is a string in the loose "format",

```
string str = "V1,B=V1,C=V1,V2,V3,D=V1,V2,A=V1,=V2,V3";
```

and a known set of Keys

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
```

How can the Key-Value pairs shown below be extracted? (Any text before the first Key should be treated as the Value for the null Key. Also the Values shown below have any trailing comma removed.)

```
Key     Value
(null)  V1
A       V1,=V2,V3     (The = here is, unfortunately, part of the value)
B       V1
C       V1,V2,V3 
D       V1,V2
```

This problem is difficult because it is *not* possible to split immediately on either the `=` or `,`.

Comment: Why is it not possible to split on `,` ?

Comment: @Kabulan0lak: He has multiple comma separated values for a single key :(

Comment: The data shown is not even consistent with itself (`,=V2,`), so "loose" is an understatement.

Comment: I honestly don't see much difference between the 2 questions.

Comment: A simple split can't do that. Assuming `=V2` is a typo for `V2`, you can extract the key/values with a regex, then filter the results using the key list and LINQ.

Comment: I would separate on `,` and add value to keys recursively. If they don't have a Key, I add it to the last Key, if they have, I create a new Key. Don't see the problem.

Comment: You can split on `,` *and* `=` (removing blanks) then sequentially process entries, when you match a key start adding to a fresh value entry. Start with a null key and you get what you wanted.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Sorry, I lost internet connectivity and couldn't fix those issues (although the = there is correct); I've made the results consistent in the Values and added a note.

Comment: Why not clean up and reword the original question? If that question got improved, what would be the difference between the two?

Comment: @Dialecticus I would, if not for it being closed with **-9** votes .. sometimes the bias gets too high.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's part of the problem - that `=` can appear as part of a value; this eliminates a direct easy split :(

Comment: We've put the other question out of its misery. It's not fair to keep that baggage around after cleaning it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignoring the known set of keys, and assuming each key appears only once:

```
string str = "V1,B=V1,C=V1,V2,V3,D=V1,V2,A=V1,=V2,V3";

var splitByEqual = new[] {'='};

var values = Regex.Split(str, @",(?=\w+=)")
    .Select(token => token.Split(splitByEqual, 2))
    .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Length == 1 ? "" : pair.First(),
                  pair => pair.Last());
```

- The regex is [pretty simple](http://regex101.com/r/yM2pC4): split by commas that are followed by a key (any alphanumeric) and an equal sign. (If we allow `A=V1,V2=V3` this wouldn't work)
- Now we have the collection {`V1`,`B=V1`,`C=V1,V2,V3`,`D=V1,V2`,`A=V1,=V2,V3`}. We split that by `=`, but not more than once.
- Next we create a dictionary. This line is a little ugly, but isn't too important - we already have the data we need. I'm also using an empty string instead of null.

---

If we do want to use the known list of keys, we can change the pattern to:

```
var splitPattern = @",(?=(?:" + String.Join("|", keys.Select(Regex.Escape))) + ")=)";
```

and use `Regex.Split(str, splitPattern)`.

Comment: What if `str` has this: `'A=V1,V2=V3,V4'`. Regex would think `V2` is a new key, when in fact it's not.

Comment: `string.Join("|", keys.Select(s => Regex.Escape(s)))` would be good to be bulletproof

Comment: @user2864740 - I was just editing the answer to account for that.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov - That is a very good point, but I started by assuming keys are alphanumeric. If keys can contain other characters we're in real trouble (at least we don't want to allow `=` and `,`). I'll put it in anyway for good practice.

Comment: There are several good answers, but this one feels the most complete and is relatively flexible for this "wonderful" pattern. Thanks!

Comment: On the other hand: what if the first part (without the key) is in the form `V1=V2`, like `str="V1=V2,B=V3"`? The code will treat `V1` as a key.

Comment: @Dialecticus - That's a good point! I'll look into that later.

Comment: This is how I fixed it: `.Select(token => Regex.IsMatch(token, splitPattern.Substring(1)) ? token.Split(splitByEqual, 2) : new [] {token})`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the keys do not also occur in the values:

- For each key,

  - search for the regexp `",|^" + KEY + "="`
- split the string at the found locations
- then process each split string individually. anything before the first = is the key, anything after is the value

Answer (score 1):

Can't you remove the leading `=` before you split? Here's an approach using `String.Split` and LINQ:

```
var pairs = str.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(x => new { KeyVals = x.TrimStart('=').Split('=') })
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Key = x.KeyVals.Length == 1 ? null : x.KeyVals[0].Trim(),
        Value = x.KeyVals.Last().Trim()
    })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
    .Select(g => new { g.Key, Values=g.Select(x => x.Value) });
```

Output:

```
foreach (var keyVal in pairs)
    Console.WriteLine("Key:{0} Values:{1}", keyVal.Key, string.Join(",", keyVal.Values)); 

Key: Values:V1,V2,V3,V2,V2,V3
Key:B Values:V1
Key:C Values:V1
Key:D Values:V1
Key:A Values:V1
```

The result is different to your desired, so maybe i'm on the wrong track. It's also not clear why you need the *"known set of Keys"*. If you want to filter by them add a `Where` before the `GroupBy`.

Comment: I gather they want to retain that `=V2` entry in the results/

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Yeah, which is a PITA (but also makes this question somewhat, FSVO, interesting) ..

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: i'm not sure if he really needs to retain it. I guess that `=V2` is just a leftover of a missing/null key.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: he has edited the question, now it's obvious that you're right ;)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, lost mah internets with a pending edit :|

Comment: @user2864740: but your desired result is still not clear. For example: why do you want `A: V1,=V2,V3`? I don't see any A-Values with `V3`. The same with the keys `C` and `D`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Neither the `,` (nor `=` not preceded by a Key) is separator but just part of the Value itself so, where the brackets denote `[Key]=[Value]` it is `[A]=[V1,=V2,V3]`

Answer (score 1):

I hate myself for going all old-school, but try replacing the leading = with another character before the split then put it back afterwards:

### Debug view of result:

[image]

```
    private static List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ExtractData(string dataString, List<string> keys)
    {
        // Convert any leading "=" to another character avoid losing it :)
        dataString = dataString.Replace(",=", ",+");

        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> result = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

        // Split on equals and comma
        var entries = dataString.Split(new char[] { '=', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        // Start with null key
        string key = null;

        // Start with blank value for each key
        string value = "";
        foreach (string entry in entries)
        {
            // Put back any removed '='
            string text = entry.Replace('+', '=');
            if (keys.Contains(entry))
            {
                // Save previous key value
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    result.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, value.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' })));
                }
                key = entry;
                value = "";
            }
            else
            {
                value += text + ",";
            }
        }
        // save last result
        result.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>(key, value.TrimEnd(new char[]{','})));
        return result;
    }
```

I know this can be shortened with LINQ etc, but no time to make it pretty :)

Comment: Ah, the step of pre-re-encoding the problematic `,=` is clever.